# Transit by road from Kuwait to Abu Dhabi

Tags: us-citizens, transit-visas

I am a US citizen and current Kuwaiti resident. I am moving to Abu Dhabi and would like to drive my car from Kuwait to Abu Dhabi. Is it possible and what is the process?

Comment: Are you talking about registering the car in the UAE? Or about the transit visa for Saudi arabia? The former fits in Expats.SE.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to obtain a 72 hour Saudi transit visa for the purpose of driving through Saudi Arabia to the UAE.

This is only possible if you are male and you are a resident of one of the Gulf States.

One man's experience of doing it is documented here: http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/trip-reports/1556689-road-trip-saudi-arabia-qatar.html